# How to make a Hangman game in JS

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a hangman game in JS. I have the following functions working. The computer displays a random word from my array. I print the keys pressed to the screen and give the user 10 keystrokes before they loose. The problem I am having is getting the array to display in the var possibleWord section so it displays as blank spaces or dashes. Thank you for your help in advance.

```js
//Computer picks random word to guess
function getItem() {
  //Possible words to guess
  var words = ['jason', 'kaitlyn', 'lora', 'matthew'];
  document.getElementById("wordGuess").innerHTML = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];

  //Displays possible words blank spaces
  var possibleWord = "J A S O N";
  var blankSpaces = "";
  var wordLength = possibleWord.length;

  for (i = 0; i < wordLength; i++) {
    var x = possibleWord.charAt(i);

    if (x === " " || x === "/'") {
      blankSpaces += x;
    } else {
      blankSpaces += "_";
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("blankSpaces").innerHTML = blankSpaces;
}

//This code captures the keypress and prints it out on the screen
var guessesLeft = 9;

document.onkeypress = function(keyPressed) {
  var keyPressed = keyPressed || window.event,
    charCode = keyPressed.keyCode || keyPressed.which,
    lettersGuessed = String.fromCharCode(charCode);

  // var userGuess = prompt("What word do you guess?");
  // var userGuess = words.split('');
  // var userGuess
  // if (words.indexOf(userGuess) > -1) {
  //  alert("Your guess is correct.")
  // }else {
  //  alert("Your guess is wrong.")
  // }

  document.getElementById("lettersGuessed").innerHTML += lettersGuessed;
  document.getElementById("guessesLeft").innerHTML = guessesLeft;

  guessesLeft--;

  if (guessesLeft === -1) {
    alert("You Loose!");
  }
}
```

```html
<body onload="getItem()">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
      Press any key to get started!
      <br>
      <br>Wins: # of times user guessed the word correctly
      <br>
      <br>Display random word from Array: <strong><u><span id="wordGuess"></span></u></strong>
      <br>
      <br>as the user guesses the correct letter, make the word display like this: <span id="blankSpaces"></span>
      <br>
      <br>Number of Guesses Remaining: <span id="guessesLeft">10</span>
      <br>
      <br>Letters Already Guessed: <span id="lettersGuessed"></span>
      <br>
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: What is it currently doing and what do you expect it to do?

Comment: It currently displays the spaces for whatever word I put in the possibleWord variable space. I would like that to be populated with the random word generated from the array I created.

Answer (score 1):

The is one of many ways to do it.

-First, you measure the `length` of the random word.

-Then create the array showing the player's progress, containing `length` number of dashes or blank spaces, like so:

```
var progressWord = []
for (var i = 0; i < wordLength; i ++)
  progressWord.push('-');
```

-On input, check if the key string (after converting it from keycode) can be found inside your `chosenWord`, using `indexOf()`. If it exists, replace the occurrences:

```
if (chosenWord.indexOf(keyString) != -1){ // if the character is found
  for (var i = 0; i < wordLength; i ++){ // loop on all characters
     if (chosenWord[i] == keyString) // if this is an occurance
       progressWord[i] = chosenWord[i];
  }
}else{
  // wrong choice
}
```

-Check if the player has won or lose.

```
if (progressWord.indexOf('-') == -1 ){ // if there are no dashes left
  //win!
}else if (guessesLeft <= 0){
  //player has lost
}
```

-Join `progressArray` using the 'join()` method and display it on the screen.

```
progressWord.join(" "); // will form a string from the array, with a space as as delimeter
```

You can always test on your browser's console. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Without going into good JavaScript (specifically polluting the global name space) and just answering your immediate question, look at this [JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q8qg40nz/8/) for displaying the underscores based on the word from your array.

```
var possibleWord = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
document.getElementById("wordGuess").innerHTML = possibleWord;
//Space out possibleWord
var originalLength = possibleWord.length;
for (i = 0; i < originalLength; i++) {
    possibleWord = [possibleWord.slice(0, i*2+1), ' ', possibleWord.slice(i*2+1)].join('');
}
```

As a minimum I've wrapped this in a [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)